# Performing a query on a result from another query?

Tags: sql, select, count, aggregate, sum

I have a the query:

```
SELECT availables.bookdate AS Date, DATEDIFF(now(),availables.updated_at) as Age
FROM availables
INNER JOIN rooms
ON availables.room_id=rooms.id
WHERE availables.bookdate BETWEEN '2009-06-25' AND date_add('2009-06-25', INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND rooms.hostel_id = 5094
GROUP BY availables.bookdate
```

Which returns something like:

```
Date               Age
2009-06-25         0
2009-06-26         2
2009-06-27         1
2009-06-28         0
2009-06-29         0
```

How can I then do a Count on the number of rows which is returned.. (in this case 5) and an SUM of the Ages?  To return just one row with the Count and the SUM?

```
Count         SUM
5             3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Usually you can plug a Query's result (which is basically a table) as the FROM clause source
of another query, so something like this will be written:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(SUBQUERY.AGE) from
(
  SELECT availables.bookdate AS Date, DATEDIFF(now(),availables.updated_at) as Age
  FROM availables
  INNER JOIN rooms
  ON availables.room_id=rooms.id
  WHERE availables.bookdate BETWEEN '2009-06-25' AND date_add('2009-06-25', INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND rooms.hostel_id = 5094
  GROUP BY availables.bookdate
) AS SUBQUERY
```

Comment: question, won't the sub query be run for each record of the outer query ? or will the result be cached

Comment: What sql server will most likely do, is just run the subquery once, and then do a stream aggregate on the result. You can see what it actually did by using the `Include Actual Execution Plan` option.

Answer (score 19):

You just wrap your query in another one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(Age)
FROM (
    SELECT availables.bookdate AS Count, DATEDIFF(now(),availables.updated_at) as Age
    FROM availables
    INNER JOIN rooms
    ON availables.room_id=rooms.id
    WHERE availables.bookdate BETWEEN '2009-06-25' AND date_add('2009-06-25', INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND rooms.hostel_id = 5094
    GROUP BY availables.bookdate
) AS tmp;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you even need to wrap it.  Won't this work?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(DATEDIFF(now(),availables.updated_at))
FROM availables
INNER JOIN rooms    ON availables.room_id=rooms.id
WHERE availables.bookdate BETWEEN '2009-06-25' 
  AND date_add('2009-06-25', INTERVAL 4 DAY)
  AND rooms.hostel_id = 5094
GROUP BY availables.bookdate);
```

If your goal is to return both result sets then you'll need to store it some place temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your initial query is probably not returning what you want:

```
SELECT availables.bookdate AS Date, DATEDIFF(now(),availables.updated_at) as Age 
FROM availables INNER JOIN rooms ON availables.room_id=rooms.id 
WHERE availables.bookdate BETWEEN  '2009-06-25' AND date_add('2009-06-25', INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND rooms.hostel_id = 5094 GROUP BY availables.bookdate
```

You are grouping by book date, but you are not using any grouping function on the second column of your query.

The query you are probably looking for is:

```
SELECT availables.bookdate AS Date, count(*) as subtotal, sum(DATEDIFF(now(),availables.updated_at) as Age)
FROM availables INNER JOIN rooms ON availables.room_id=rooms.id
WHERE availables.bookdate BETWEEN '2009-06-25' AND date_add('2009-06-25', INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND rooms.hostel_id = 5094
GROUP BY availables.bookdate
```